# How does changing the kernel density search radius affect the units expressed in the map legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-statistics, kernel-density

I'm trying to understand how ArcGIS 10.1 handles [kernel density](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Kernel_Density_works/009z00000011000000/) values and how these values are reported in the legend.  For example, the following parameters were used for the KDEs in the attached figure:

*Projection Info*

- Projection: UTM 17N
- Linear Unit: M

*KDE Tool Parameters*

- Output cell size: 0.01
- Search Radius: 1m (left image) and 2m (right image)
- Area Units: SQUARE_MAP_UNITS

I know cell size has no affect on the legend values.  Yet how does the search radius affect the legend values? For example, if the search radius = 1m, then the area = pi.  And if the search radius = 2, then the area = 4pi.  Does ArcGIS automatically scale this to the projection map units (e.g. 1 m^2)?  Specifically, what are the units displayed here?

[image]

Comment: You have it backwards, all that matters is the cell size for the raster in interpreting the *density*. Unfortunately, many different programs report the density estimates in different units (confusing - a related prob. in stats are histograms reporting different units). Does the sum of your raster equal the number of original units used for the density estimation?